# Cercanía proporcional entre números

Tags: java, array

Necesito calcular si un número se considera cercano a otro pero de forma proporcional, he leído algunos documentos, libros y artículos sobre este tema junto con clústering pero no lo comprendo muy bien, intenté crear una fórmula pero esta fracasó debido a que solo daba 3 distancias para todo.

Ejemplo, si tenemos una lista de números [0.98,1,0.01,10,40,100] sabemos que los cercanos a 1 son 0.98 y 0.01 pero no nos podemos basar solo en la comparación directa de 1 con X, si no que necesitamos saber el total de números y distancias y de esta proporcionalidad extraer los números cercanos. Añado código actual. Agradezco su aporte :)

```
ArrayList<Integer> population = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //poblacion
int max = population.get(population.size()-1);
int top = population.get(0);
for(int individuals = 0; individuals < population.size()-1, individuals++){
    if((max - (Math.abs(population.get(individuals) - top)/max)) < 31 ){
        //es cercano
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el código que has puesto hay errores de concepto. Estás tomando el primer y último elemento como límites de tus cálculos, pero con eso no consigues lo que quieres.

La respuesta más sencilla es aplicar métodos estadísticos bien conocidos. Y en concreto, si calculas la media y desviación típica de tus datos, puedes calcular cuánto se desvían esos números de la media. Luego es cuestión de qué consideres lejano: sigma, 2sigma, 3sigma.

Por supuesto aquí hay un problema: no quieres saber cuánto se desvían los números de la media, sino cuánto se separan de un número concreto. Lo que se me ocurre es que calcules la media de tus datos, midas la diferencia con el número que buscas, y luego restes esa diferencia a todos tus datos del vector (quizá en otro vector copia, por ejemplo). Así consigues que las relaciones de distancia entre los números se mantengan, mientras que la media ahora coincide con el número base que tomas como referencia.

Con ese vector nuevo, restada la diferencia entre la media y el valor referencia, calculas su desviación típica, o alguna otra métrica que te sirva. Lo que quede por debajo de un límite (normalmente tiene que ver con la desviación típica) es cercano, mientras lo que quede por encima de ese límite es lejano.

Ahora bien, la desviación típica depende de los datos que tengas, y será más precisa si tienes más datos y estos están poco dispersos. Si tienes muchos datos muy dispersos, puede que este método te sirva o puede que quieras afinar más con otra métrica.

**Edición: Ejemplo**

Con tus datos en un vector:

`vectorOriginal = (0.98, 1, 0.01, 10, 40, 100)`

Calculas la media aritmética (por simplicidad solo pongo resultado y no algoritmo), que si no me he equivocado es:

`mediaOriginal = 25.33`

Calculas la diferencia de la media con el valor base que usas:

```
valorBase = 1
diferencia = 25.33 - valorBase = 24.33
```

Con esto obtienes un nuevo vector:

`vectorNuevo = (-23.35, -23.33, -24.32, -14.33, 15.67, 75.67)`

Cuya media es 1. Si ahora calculas su desviación típica, puedes descartar los elementos que más se alejen de la media.

Imagina que cojo el 50 y el -49 como límites: Queda claro que se descartaría el 75.67.

Lo malo de esta forma es que solo da un resultado preciso si muchos de los datos están cerca del número referencia que buscas, ya que los que están cerca terminarán por aplicárseles una diferencia, con lo que los estamos alejando.

Por tanto, puedes, según tus datos de entrada, probar otra alternativa: calcula un solo número que contrarreste la desviación de la media, para no cambiar los datos iniciales. Entonces la media y la desviación no deformarán tus datos de entrada.

Comment: ¿Me puedes dar un ejemplo para entender mejor tu lógica? Me parece una muy buena solución, sin embargo, no logro entenderla al 100%